# Встреча участников сообщества Stack Overflow в Москве!

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

Спешу анонсировать вторую встречу участников сообщества Stack Overflow в Москве 9 декабря 2016 года.

Уже традиционно мы соберемся дружной компанией и будем общаться на свободные темы.

Конкретное место встречи и тематика определится по результатам опроса. После определения места и времени, я обязательно отпишусь всем участникам по почте, указанной в учётной записи на Stack Overflow на русском.

Пожалуйста, помните, приглашены все участники, и даже если вы не живете в Москве! :)

- Чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32579/
- Форма регистрации на встречу: https://goo.gl/gex1GI

*Бонус*. В этом году, с большой вероятностью, встречу сможет посетить [@Sklivvz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz?tab=profile). Вы сможете задать ему любой технический (и не только!) вопрос про Stack Overflow в непринужденной обстановке!

С нетерпением ждем ваших откликов!

Comment: Как-то восторженных откликов мало...

Comment: (Восторженный отклик!) но меня не будет, дата неудобная) приятно пообщаться вам там)

Comment: если ни чего внезапно не поменяется, было бы отличным завершением рабочей недели

Comment: @Утка неудобный сезон, видимо. Все на югах :)

Comment: К сожалению, тоже не смогу присутствовать, а очень хотел. Семейные дела, отбуду из Москвы на выходные.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Жалко! Крайне хотел послушать ваш опыт проведения московских встреч.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Не представляешь, как мне жалко. С прошлого нового года ждал, но у сестры 50 лет, и сестра в Казани. Билеты куплены, лыжи навострены. А встречи действительно проходят, сегодня как раз очередная, и вся благодаря meetup.com, про который мне и рассказали на прошлых посиделках.

Comment: Как раз в Москве в эти дни; пришёл бы при наличии какого-нибудь оговорённого плана, формата (или применялись бы современные стратегии принятия решений без заранее намеченного плана), но не «свободные темы». От каковых вряд ли Stack Overflow получит много пользы. Желаю надавить на Sklivvz в плане внедрения полезных нововведений. Спасибо.

Comment: приятно замечать что это замечательное сообщество организует реальные встречи :) по поводу данной, не смогу прийти - но буду рад присутствовать на следующей, и особенно если будет в питере ! намечается ли что-то в январе ?

Comment: @ampawd В [Петербурге](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3792/) была совсем недавно.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Главная цель найшей встреч – познакомиться ближе в реальной жизни с теме, кого вы давно знаете, но никогда не видели. 

Какое–то время назад англоязычное сообщество [проводило встречи в формате конференций](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/stack-overflow-developer-days-conference/), но со временем отказались от этого